# set Dynamic height for SSRS stacked bar chart Report

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I create SSRS stacked bar chart and table.I create the table under the Chart.

I need to dynamically adjust the height of the SSRS chart based on the rows count .

I use like the following Expression in Dynamic Height Area (1 + COUNTROWS("DataSet1")/2) & " in".

But the chart will overwrite above the table.because the table has fixed.

I need to show the chart with dynamic height property and need to show the table under the chart.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new table with one column and two rows, then put the chart in the top row and the table in the bottom row (so you have a table within a table), this should get around the dynamic sizing problem.